# Autocompletion list on chrome design

Tags: css, angularjs, google-chrome, zurb-foundation

I have to submit a problem to you today.
Since a few weeks my website have a design issue on chrome, my autocompletion list is now a total hell...

Before :

[image: Before]

After :

[image: After]

I want the list come to first plan but it's not accept it anymore.
To be honest i don't understand the issue here, I doesn't touch this part of the code since month ago.

Do you have any idea ou suggestions to make ?

Thanks for you time !

Comment: I am able to see the issue on your site. It looks like a very frustrating problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got a solution that would work for you.

**CSS:**

```
.panel.bk {
    background: #f0f0f0;
    border: 1px solid #a3a3a3;
    border-top: 0;
    border-bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

#part-address-1 {
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}
```